# MySQL: SELECT Like and char_length

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a query, something like this: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_name LIKE "keyword%" AND CHAR_LENGTH("keyword%")<20`. I know this one is wrong and it's not working, but what's the right way to get the right results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not try

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table 
WHERE   field_name LIKE "keyword%" 
AND     CHAR_LENGTH(field_name)<20
```

Answer (score 0):

CHAR_LENGTH should be used with field_name not the like pattern: "keyword%"

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_name LIKE "keyword%" AND CHAR_LENGTH(field_name)<20
```